# VideoJS player gets stuck with IE9

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, html, html5-video

I'm trying to implement HTML5 Video in a site and for that I'm using VideoJS, so far it works great in Firefox and Chrome but my problem comes when I try to play the video with IE9. The player would load and when I click on the Play button, the loading image would appear and it would get stuck without doing anything.

I've checked other websites and they suggest that the MIME Type that the server is sending is wrong but I've checked already that and it's not the case.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you checked to make sure you are mp4 file is using the H.264 compression scheme?

Comment: Indeed that was my problem :)

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is common, and the above answer barely scratches the surface.

MP4 files neet to have their indexes written ahead of the video data within the file. IE isn't freezing, it's actually downloading your video all at once. You can inspect this from your console.

The fix is very simple. Download the AIR application QTIndexSwapper2, and run your MP4 files through it. Reload those files to your server and they will seamlessly stream through the VideoJS SWF Player.

Make sure you have controls and autplay