# video.js videos get stuck in IE9 and IE10, double length on Mac Safari

Tags: html, internet-explorer, safari, video.js

my videos seem to work on most platforms, including IE6-7-8, but they get stuck at the loading screen with IE9 and IE10. This happens both locally and on the web.

A smaller problem: on the latest Safari version on Mac they play twice, with audio playing only during the first instance of the video (the duration is doubled).

Anyway, here is one of the videos for instance: http://www.csdalbenga.it/videos/sonnyinterview.html

I have already checked out this question: [VideoJS player gets stuck with IE9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8883154/videojs-player-gets-stuck-with-ie9)

but the videos are actually encoded in the correct h264 format and QTIndexSwapper2 tells me the videos are fine.

It seems to be an issue specific to video.js, because if I use the default HTML5 video player, the video displays just fine.

Do you have any suggestions?

EDIT: I seem to have fixed this by adding a full path to the video instead of a relative path. So what I'm wondering is, why is a full path needed only with IE9 and IE10, and only if I use video.js instead of the standard video player?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check your MIME types. I had this exact same problem, and noticed I had forgotten to set MIME types for mp4, ogg, and webm.